# CentOS environment paths setup

Tags: linux, centos

i have installed android sdk on CentOS , i want to add sdk command line tools “android” and “avd” to Environment path so that adb , avd and android commands work in terminal .   on windows its easy do't know how to do it on CentOS

i have installed android SDK on non root account which is "lexa" , when i login to lexa through tiger vnc android SDk path is

```
Home/Android/Sdk/
```

i try to add it with

```
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=Android/Sdk/' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools' >> ~/.profile
```

but in terminal when type adb its say unknown command

Comment: Add them to .bash_profile

Comment: add it to bash_profile ... still not working .. adb command not found

Comment: Where is the question? Please edit your post and include an interrogative sentence. While you are add it make the post more understandable, by 1) correctly spell ( i→I, do't→don't, its→it's), consistently capitalize acronyms (SDK/SDk) and beginnings of sentences ( on windows/ i have) and don't insert extra spaces before punctuation ("terminal ."). A more easily readable post, with fewer distracting errors and inconsistencies, increases your chances of an answer (assuming you have a question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok adding variables to     ~/.bashrc

add through nano

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

or just run in terminal to append to bashrc

```
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=Android/Sdk/' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools' >> ~/.bashrc
```

worked

thanks